# Update UITextField's text from within a Custom Input View

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, inputview

I am showing a custom **inputView** for my **UITextField** like so

```
let inputView = UIView()
let button = UIButton()
inputView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
inputView.addSubview(button)

let tf = UITextField()
tf.inputView = inputView
```

Now when the button is clicked I would like the **tf** (UITextField)'s text to change.

In other words - from within my **inputView** how can I access the parent UITextField ?

Thanks!

Comment: `inputView` could be an instance of a subclass of `UIView` which contains a reference to a `UITextField` object that you set to `tf` (`tf` is not the `inputView` parent)

Comment: Right. Although I would need to explicitly set the reference right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: Right :) Was hoping I didnt need to do that. Looks like my only option though :)